# Multiple rendering causing a ul more

Tags: 7, routes, theming

I had following code in template.php this is in `function bartik_process_page(&$variables)`

```
 $main_menu_tree = menu_tree_all_data('main-menu');
 $variables['main_menu_expanded'] = menu_tree_output($main_menu_tree);
```

and in page.tpl.php

```
<?php if ($main_menu): ?>
                    <div id="main-menu" class="navigation">
                        <?php print render($main_menu_expanded); ?>
                    </div> <!-- /#main-menu -->
        <?php endif; ?> 
                          <?php if ($main_menu): ?>
                    <div id="main-menu" class="navigation">
                        <?php print render($main_menu_expanded); ?>
                    </div> <!-- /#main-menu -->
        <?php endif; ?> 
                            <?php if ($main_menu): ?>
                    <div id="main-menu" class="navigation">
                        <?php print render($main_menu_expanded); ?>
                    </div> <!-- /#main-menu -->
        <?php endif; ?>
```

and output it is like this in bartik

1

```
    <ul class="menu clearfix"><li class="first last leaf"><a href="/ji/" class="active">Home</a></li>
</ul>
```

2. Now u can see i m getting `<ul class="menu">` extra

```
<div class="navigation" id="main-menu">
                        <ul class="menu clearfix"><ul class="menu clearfix"><li class="first last leaf"><a class="active" href="/ji/">Home</a></li>
</ul></ul>                    </div>
```

Any idea how can i stop it[image]

Comment: Why do you need 3 IF STATEMENT in page.tpl.php with the same condition. Because it is repeated 3 times so the menu will be generated 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer of it since in render variables are passed by reference https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/render/7

so i was passing $main_menu_expanded multiple times in render which was culprit.

Fix is

```
$variables['main_menu_expanded'] = render(menu_tree_output($main_menu_tree));
<?php if ($main_menu): ?>
                    <div id="main-menu" class="navigation">
                        <?php print ($main_menu_expanded); ?>
                    </div> <!-- /#main-menu -->
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($main_menu): ?>
                    <div id="main-menu" class="navigation">
                        <?php print ($main_menu_expanded); ?>
                    </div> <!-- /#main-menu -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Now i dont get extra ul